# VBA, JSONConverter from Github, Trouble with multiple levels of json data

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, jsonconverter

Afternoon All,
I'm using the VBA-TOOLS > JSONConverter from GITHUB.    I have it working for the first "layer" or "level" of my JSON string but I cannot get it to drop down a level.

If you look at my example code, the first "level", fields id/createdAt/updatedAt will all show in a simple messagebox.  If I try and go down one level to what's within properties, I keep getting the error shown below.  I tried two different ways/lines of code, trying to display the value of the first field within properties.

I am passing the code below a JSON string.  Here is the data two ways:
1.) This is the raw string

```
{"id":"448401",
 "properties":{
     "createdate":"2021-11-11T22:28:15.015Z",
     "email":"steven.mcnulty@otis.com",
     "firstname":"Steven",
     "hs_object_id":"448401",
     "lastmodifieddate":"2023-03-31T17:42:31.620Z",
     "lastname":"McNulty"
  },
  "createdAt":"2021-11-11T22:28:15.015Z",
  "updatedAt":"2023-03-31T17:42:31.620Z",
  "archived":false
}
```

2.) This is a snippet from POSTMAN making the same get request:
[Postman_Get_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu1rx.png)

**My code:**

```
Function json_convert(temp As String)

Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(temp)


'WORKING
MsgBox (Json("id"))
MsgBox (Json("createdAt"))


'NOT WORKING
MsgBox (Json("properties")(1)("createdate"))
MsgBox (Json("id")("properties")(1)("createdate"))

End Function
```

[excel_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFbu1.png)

These details are above.

Comment: Try `Json("properties")("createdate")`

Comment: And `Json("id")` does not have any sub-levels

Comment: Thank you, removing the 1 did it.  The Github page had a YT video link at the bottom and the video showed that digit in place, something to do with a indexing value.